# Application of Leibniz Rule?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, random-matrices

Define $\text{D}$ to be the set of density matrices on some finite dimensional Hilbert space and suppose that I have a density matrix $\rho$ parametrized by some scalar $\theta$. I have an integral that looks like this $\int_{\text{D}} \frac{d\rho(\theta)}{d\theta} \, d\rho(\theta)$ where $d\rho$ is the uniform distribution on the set of density matrices. Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\text{D}} \frac{d\rho(\theta)}{d\theta} \, d\rho(\theta) = \frac{d}{d\theta} \int_{\text{D}}\rho(\theta) \, d\rho(\theta) .
\end{equation}

The integral doesn't precisely fit into the requirements for the Leibniz rule because $\theta$ also appears in the differential. If the statement isn't true, do the two integrals differ by some small error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a simple case where $D$ is an interval and $\rho$ is differentiable.  Then I expect
$$
\int_D \frac{d\rho(\theta)}{d\theta}\;d\rho(\theta)
\quad\text{means}\quad
\int_D \frac{d\rho(\theta)}{d\theta}\;\frac{d\rho(\theta)}{d\theta}\;d\theta
\tag1$$
and
$$
\int_D\rho(\theta)\;d\rho(\theta)
\quad\text{means}\quad
\int_D\rho(\theta)\;\frac{d\rho(\theta)}{d\theta}\;d\theta
\tag2$$
Then the Leibniz rule would say (from the product rule)
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_D\rho(\theta)\;d\rho(\theta) =
\int_D\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\rho(\theta)\;\frac{d\rho(\theta)}{d\theta}\right)\;d\theta
=
\int_D \left(\rho(\theta)\;\frac{d^2\rho(\theta)}{d\theta^2}
+\frac{d\rho (\theta)}{d\theta}\;\frac{d\rho(\theta)}{d\theta}
\right)\;d\theta
$$
This is not $(1)$.

If $\rho(\theta)$ has the form $a\theta+b$, then the second derivative is $0$, so in that case you will get what you propose.